# convert external arguments into list

Tags: python

I need to run a script with external arguments where first argument should be a int the second an list : example :

python run_eval_ML.py  5 "(2,4,6,8)"

When I run the script I get :

```
(base) MyPC:ML$ python run_eval_ML.py 5 "(2,4,5,8)" 
run_eval_ML.py 
5 
(2,4,5,8) 
param_grid {'n_neighbors': '(2,4,5,8)'}
```

#
First ARGV: 5 : OK

But The second argument should be this type : (2,4,5,8) and not '(2,4,5,8)'

When I assign

```
var2=sys.argv[2]
```

and I re assign

```
param_grid = {'n_neighbors':var2}
```

I get

```
param_grid {'n_neighbors': '(2,4,5,8)'}
```

and not

```
param_grid {'n_neighbors': (2,4,5,8)}
```

Thank you in advance if you can help

Rgds Carlos

Comment: system sends all as string so run with  `"2,4,5,8"` and use `sys.argv[2] .split(',')` to create list. If you need numbers then you have to convert to integer `var2 = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[2] .split(',')]` or `var2 = list(map(int, sys.argv[2] .split(',')))`

Comment: BTW: first argument is string `"5"` not integer `5` so you may have to convert it too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

System sends all as strings so you have to split it to list and convert every element to integer

Run without `()`

```
python run_eval_ML.py 5 "2,4,5,8"
```

and then

```
# split to list of strings
var2 = sys.argv[2].split(",")

# convert to list of integers
var2 = [int(x) for x in var2]
```

or in one line

```
var2 = [int(x) for x in sys.argv[2].splti(",")]
```

or using `map()`

```
var2 = list(map(int, sys.argv[2].splti(",")))
```

---

You have also convert first argument from string to integer

```
var1 = int(sys.argv[1])
```